# arm-none-eabi linker references unused symbols

Tags: linker, arm, embedded, bare-metal

I am seeing an issue with gcc. I have a project for an NXP processor in CMake that builds but I'm getting some weird errors.

This is bare metal and I don't need or intend to support semihosting. Some of the NXP code uses assert() and becomes __assert_func() which gets pulled in from libc.a, libc_nano.a, libg.a or libg_nano.a, from arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.mpacbti-rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/thumb/v6-m/nofp .

But when __assert_func() gets pulled in, it also pulls in a bunch of other stuff that never gets called, like _lseek_r, etc. A lot of normal libc type functions that are never referenced. I used objdump -S to disassemble the ELF file and they are never called.

I have searched on the internet a bunch and some people are saying that all I need to do is include a file that has stubs out all of those calls. I'm working on a project where one of the code standards are no dead or unutilized calls. Providing stubs would not work.

I wrote my own __assert_func() and that doesn't get pulled in any more.

The extraneous symbols are no longer in the ELF file, but when it links I see

thisc:/users/daniel/tools/12.2_mpacbti-rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/users/daniel/tools/12.2_mpacbti-rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/thumb/v6-m/nofp\libg_nano.a(libc_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':

writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x10): warning: _write is not implemented and will always fail:

I see that for _close, _seek, _read, and _write.

These are my link options in CMake

add_link_options(-Wl,-gc-sections,--print-memory-usage,-Map=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.map)
add_link_options(-mfloat-abi=soft -mcpu=${MCPU} -mthumb -mthumb-interwork --specs=nosys.specs --specs=nano.specs -o ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf)

The problem, as I see it, is that the linker seems to think that I need these other function calls, even when they end up getting removed from the ELF file.

I tried everything I could think of to fix this.  I've changed the linker options, order of libraries, called out specific libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:
After adding my own __assert_func(), I removed --specs=nosys.specs from the linker options and it seems to have worked.